# How to move or modify the position of the redo panel?

Tags: customization, properties, operator, theme

The panel is always minimized, I have to enlarge it and move my head to bottom left each time:

[image]

Does anyone know of any modifications or plugins that will allow me to move this window? Or even dock it to the right panel (<kbd>N</kbd>)?

Comment: sorry, don't think such a thing exists.  Unless you are willing to code something that will move it yourself.

Comment: just close it and use F9  to have the same information on  a floating window.

Comment: Also, once you open it once, it defaults to open for all future actions (until you minimize it again).

Comment: If you want to increase the size of the UI elements (to make things more accessible on a 4K display, perhaps), you can do so by going under `User Preferences > Interface`  and increasing the _Resolution Scale_. However, this changes the size of far more than just the _Operator Panel_, I'm afraid.